# Need help to echo variable after finding a value

Tags: shell, scripting

My requirement is like below.

```
txt="Notepad"
doc="Microsoft Word"
xls="Microsoft Excel"
pst="Microsoft Outlook"
```

for a file name I need to find the file extn. if extn is txt, then I should echo "Notepad", if ext is xls, then I should echo "Microsoft excel"

below are the codes which I tried but not getting the correct output

```
filename=/admin/phase1/project/summary_copy_new.txt

onlyfilename=`basename $filename`
echo $onlyfilename
```

getting the answer as summary_copy_new.txt

```
ext=`echo "$onlyfilename##*.}"`
echo $ext
```

getting the answer as txt

now if I give below commands, I am not getting "Notepad" as the answer

```
echo "$""$ext"
```

I am getting the output as $txt. 
but I need "Notepad" as the output.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

For the indirect variable expansion use the `${!name}` construction. e.g. for

```
txt="Notepad"
ext="txt"
echo "${!ext}"
#Notepad
```

Also, while the `"$onlyfilename##*.}"` could work, as:

```
ext="${onlyfilename##*.}"
```

you meet problems when the file doesn't has any extension, e.g.

```
file="some"
ext=${file##*.}
echo "$ext"
#some
```

the result is clearly incorrect. Therefore is better using regular expressions.

Full demo for your app:

```
txt="Notepad"
doc="Microsoft Word"
xls="Microsoft Excel"
pst="Microsoft Outlook"
gz="gzip"

while read -r file
do
        base=$(basename "$file")
        [[ $base =~ ^([^.]*)\.(.*)$ ]] && ext=${BASH_REMATCH[2]} || ext="NOTHING"
        printf "%-12s extension is: %-8s program is: %s\n" "$base" "$ext" "${!ext:-PROGRAM_UNDEFINED}"
done <<'EOF'
/some/text.txt
/spaced dir/excel.xls
/spacedname/e mail.pst
/undefinedext/word.docx
/multidot/file.tar.gz
/no/extension
EOF
```

prints

```
text.txt     extension is: txt      program is: Notepad
excel.xls    extension is: xls      program is: Microsoft Excel
e mail.pst   extension is: pst      program is: Microsoft Outlook
word.docx    extension is: docx     program is: PROGRAM_UNDEFINED
file.tar.gz  extension is: tar.gz   program is: PROGRAM_UNDEFINED
extension    extension is: NOTHING  program is: PROGRAM_UNDEFINED
```

The problem with the above is than you **can't** define a program for e.g. `tar.gz` because you can't define a variable with dot such: `tar.gz="tar"`.

Thereofre (and many other reasons) is better to use `associative arrays`.

```
declare -A prg_for=(
[txt]="Notepad"
[doc]="Microsoft Word"
[xls]="Microsoft Excel"
[pst]="Microsoft Outlook"
[gz]="gzip"
[tar.gz]="tar"
)

while read -r file
do
    base=$(basename "$file")
    [[ $base =~ ^([^.]*)\.(.*)$ ]] && ext=${BASH_REMATCH[2]} || ext="NOTHING"
    printf "extension is: %10s program is: %s\n" "$ext" "${prg_for[$ext]:-PROGRAM_UNDEFINED}"
done <<'EOF2'
/some/text.txt
/spaced dir/excel.xls
/spacedname/e mail.pst
/undefinedext/word.docx
/multidot/file.tar.gz
/no/extension
EOF2
```

what correctly prints `tar` for the `tar.gz` extension

```
extension is:        txt program is: Notepad
extension is:        xls program is: Microsoft Excel
extension is:        pst program is: Microsoft Outlook
extension is:       docx program is: PROGRAM_UNDEFINED
extension is:     tar.gz program is: tar
extension is:    NOTHING program is: PROGRAM_UNDEFINED
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a call to the eval command like this:

```
eval echo "$""$ext"
```

The output of this command is the content of the txt variable: Notepad.

Comment: Thank u so much for the very quick help.

Comment: the `eval` could be pretty dangerous... the `${!name}` is much cleaner anyway.

Comment: @jm666 Nice i don't know this way to do that!For a simple echo you are right it's with `${!name}`the must be done. Eval is an overkill in this case.